# LINQ to SQL DBML in central class library - accessing specific site DB

Tags: asp.net, class, c#-4.0, linq-to-sql

I Have a centralised class library that a bunch of my sites use. Each site has it's own DB. I would like to add LINQ to SQL functionality to this class library but in such a way that it accesses the relevant DB of the site calling it.

So, if I have Site A,B and C, with database dbA,dbB and dbC all using CentralLibrary.dll

I would like a CentralLibrary.dll to use dbA when site A calls it, dbB when site B calls it...and so on.

Possible? I am seeing hard-coded connection strings in files like settings.settings, settings.design.cs and the DBML file itself. Presumably I need a way of dynamically changing these depending on the site using the library.

Comment: Do all this databases (dbA, dbB and dbC) have the same schemes (same tables, stored procedures, views etc.) and differ only by the actual content?

Comment: Essentially yes, there will be some unique tables in each DB, however, 90% of tables, SPs etc. will be identical and any references from the class library will be to tables that are 100% definitely in ALL databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all databases are the same (at least the part that is used by the CentralLibrary), then here is what you can do.

Create a single LINQ context and add all necessary DB objects in it (make sure you've added only objects that are common for all your DBs). You can do this either in CentralLibrary itself, or in any dll that will be used by it. Then whenever any specific site needs to go to the database, it will be supposed to pass the corresponding connection string. Of course CentralLibary API should be able to handle it properly (some kind of initialization is in order here).

To connect to the database CentralLibrary will create a LINQ to SQL context. The key point is that LINQ generates a constructor for data context that accepts connection string as a parameter. Here is the sample declaration in .designer.cs file:

```
public SampleDataContext(string connection) : base(connection, mappingSource)
```

If data context is created with this constructor, it ignores all the hardcoded strings whenever they are declared (app.config, .designer.cs, settings, etc.). And now, after data context is created, CentralLibrary will work with every database exactly the same way.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I'm pretty new to LINQ and am in fact trying to make it work with the set up we previously used in here. By the sounds of what you're saying it is possible but I'm a little confused. In the ClassLibrary.dll do I create a new object (sampleDataContext in the eg. above) and then call that object when connecting to the library? At the moment I'm calling a dataContext this way: var sampleDataContext = new SampleDataContext(); and the sampleDataContext is defined from the DBML auto-generated when I drag tables into the project. Hope this is clear!

Comment: `SampleDataContext` is a class generated by Visual Studio for you. It has several constructors defined "out-of-the-box", so to say. You can find all the declarations in the SampleDataContext.designer.cs file. The one you are using right now takes the connection string from the assembly settings (declaration looks like `SampleDataContext() : base(global::SomeNamespace.Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString1, mappingSource)`). There are also other constructors declared, and basically I suggest to use one of those.

Comment: Excellent, makes sense now. Looks perfect as well, I've looked in the designer.cs file and see the various constructors. The one you suggest looks perfect for what we're after. Thanks again.